# Shortcut key Chrome extension doesn't works

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I try to add some shortcut keyboard for my new extension Chrome, it doesn't work. When I try to check my command with this line :

```
chrome.commands.getAll(command => { alert(JSON.stringify(command)) })
```

The description and the name is displaying correctly, but the shortcut property render an empty string. I've tried so many shortcut, delete et re-install my unpackaged extension after that, it doesn't work always.

My manifest.json :

```js
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "myfirstext",
    "version": "1.0.0",

    "description": "blablabla",

    "author": {
        "name": "Ben Lmsc",
        "url": "https://github.com"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["js/main.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html"
    },
    "commands": {
        "handle_my_key": {
            "suggested_key": {
                "default": "Ctrl+Shift+L"
            },
            "description": "Description of my shortcut"
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "img/LOGO_16.png",
        "32": "img/LOGO_32.png",
        "48": "img/LOGO_48.png",
        "128": "img/LOGO_128.png"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*",
        "notifications"
    ]
}
```

Comment: What happens of you assign the hotkey in chrome://extensions/shortcuts dialog?

Comment: Are you doing this on a Mac or Windows?

Comment: Nothing is assigned in chrome://extensions/shortcuts dialog. I'm doing this on mac. I've tried to remove the Ctrl (or Command) on my mac, it works. The browser don't wan't when I use Ctrl+Shift+(Y, L, ...)